# How do I query a full (or partial) name built from two separate model CharFields (first_name and last_name) in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to query a users full name using but am having some trouble. When I query either 'John' **OR** 'Doe' I get the correct result, but when I query 'John Doe' I do not.

While I know my query is explicitly structured that way (first_name **OR** last_name), my question is how do I combine the fields such that any of 'John Doe', 'John Do', 'Jon D', etc. would produce the correct result?

**Model:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.last_name.title()}, {self.first_name.title()}"
```

**View:**

```
def search_results(request):

query = request.GET.get('q')
person_list = Person.objects.filter(
    Q(first_name__icontains=query) | Q(last_name__icontains=query))
context = {'person_list': person_list}
return render(request, 'myapp/search_results.html', context)
```

Comment: You need to use [**`Concat`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) to create a full name expression and then query over the expression. IMO, your solution (the `OR`ing) is just fine

Comment: Using an **or** does not produce results for a partial or full combination of the two fields. When searching for a person named John Doe using 'John Doe', no results would be produced because 'John Doe' is not first_name or last_name. I will try concat though.. I had tried before but was getting an error suggesting that I could not use with CharField.